# Prove or disprove any continous map $f$ from $T^2$ to $RP^2$ is null-homotopic.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, group-cohomology

I tried to solve the following question: Prove or disprove any continous map f from $T^2$ to $RP^2$ is null-homotopic. We know the universal cover of $RP^2$ is $S^2.$ I want to construct a map $g$ from $T^2$ to $S^2.$ Then,  I will deduce that since $S^2$ is not contractible, then $g$ is not null-homotopic. How do you construct such a map?

Comment: This proof won't work directly as stated. For example, you could just use a constant map to map the torus to $S^2$ and that wouldn't solve the problem. You could also construct surjective maps that are nulhomotopic. You need a map to the sphere that is not nulhomotopic, and you need to know that the composition with the covering map is not nulhomotopic.

Comment: Why does the fact that $S^2$ is not contractible imply that $g:T^2 \to S^2$ is not null-homotopic?

Comment: You can't necessarily lift a map from $\mathbb{T}^2\to \mathbb{RP}^2$ to map from $\mathbb{T}^2$ to the universal cover ($\mathbb{S}^2$) of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ since $\mathbb{T}^2$ isn't simply connected ...

Comment: You're probably going to want to construct a map that induces a nontrivial homomorphism on the fundamental group.

Comment: *Hint*: Can you answer this question if $\mathbb{T}^2$ is replaced by the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1$?

Comment: If i sent a generator of $T^2$ to $S^1$ in $RP^2$ which is a generator and the rest of them to a point, is it work?

Comment: @Mücahit Meral You can also map the Klein bottle into RP2 so that the composition with the 2 fold covering by the torus is not null homotopic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a little more work your idea works fine to construct a non-null-homotopic map. This is a different idea than the one Amitesh Datta is suggesting in the comments.

Pick a small ball in $T^2$, and collapse everything outside it. This gives a map $f: T^2 \to S^2$ which induces an isomorphism on second homology, and is therefore not null-homotopic. Compose with the projection $S^2 \to \Bbb{RP}^2$.

I claim that the map $pf: T^2 \to \Bbb{RP}^2$ is not null-homotopic. By construction, $pf$ lifts to a map $f: T^2 \to S^2$, so we can lift homotopies (and in particular, null-homotopies) of $pf$ by the homotopy lifting property, which covering spaces satisfy. The endpoint of this lift would be a map $T^2 \to S^2$ whose image is contained in two points (the inverse image of a point in $\Bbb{RP}^2$ under $p$); because $T^2$ is connected, the image is contained in a single point.

Thus we've constructed a null-homotopy of $f$, which is impossible as $f$ induces an isomorphism on second homology - it can't be null-homotopic. So $pf$ was not null-homotopic.

Comment: thanks a lot for your comments

Comment: @Mike Miller Mike, a couple of questions.  It seems that your construction will work for any orientable manifold, that is, by collapsing the complement of a closed ball to a point one would get a map into the sphere of homology degree 1. Yes? Also can't the map be chosen to have any degree, not just 1? Finally, I am curious what the induced vector bundle looks like. It is not trivial because the pull back of the Euler class is not zero (in even dimensions). Also it seems that in the interior of the ball, the induced bundle can be identified with the tangent bundle but not along the boundary.

Comment: @JoeS: Yeah, both of those observations are valid; to get any degree I prefer just to do this and then compose with the degree $n$ self-map of the sphere. I think there's a name for this "collapse all but a ball" map, but I don't know it. I guess I probably prefer to think of that bundle in terms of clutching functions; it's trivial in the complement of the ball, and it's trivial on the ball, so we get a transition function on the $S^{n-1}$ between the two trivializations. It seems to me this is the same as the clutching function for $TS^n$.

Comment: @Mike Miller I looked at the last chapter of Milnor's Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint. It  generalizes your construction to sub manifolds with trivial normal bundle. One projects a tubular neighborhood onto an open ball and identifies the complement of the neighborhood to a point. The dimension of the sphere is the fiber dimension of the normal bundle. Your example is the case of a point with tubular neighborhood an open ball. Would you get a map of degree n if you close n points rather than one?

Comment: @JoeS: Is that really a manifold? It seems to me that doing this with two points in, say, the sphere, gives you $(D^n \sqcup D^n)/\partial(D^n \sqcup D^n) = S^n \vee S^n$. In any case, if it is, you should still get a map of degree 1. The key is remembering the smooth definition of degree: pick a regular value, and take an oriented count of the points in its preimage. Because the map is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism on a neighborhood of a point, it has degree 1.

Comment: @Mike Miller I will read through the proof. It seems that once the normal bundles are oriented one can choose an oriented basis for each and parameterize the normal directions with n-k parameters. Projection onto the parameter vectors maps each component to the same open ball so you only get a single sphere after identifying the rest of the manifold to a point. The parameters would come from geodesic normal coordinates. It also seems that one has the freedom to choose orientations of the normal bundle so I do not see why the map has to have positive degree.

Comment: It seems I don't understand the construction you're talking about. Sorry about the red herring above. I agree that one has the freedom to choose orientations; I just picked the one that gave me positive degree. Sorry for not being explicit. You might post what you're asking as a separate question.